# Creating cookies from background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a background script in my extension that creates a context menu item and handles it. When it is clicked, a cookie is created with specific details. Here is the source for that file:

script.js

```
function createC() {
    var x = 1;
    var y = 2;
    //Create Cookie
    document.cookie = document.URL + "=" + " " + x + " " + y + " ; " + 4102444799;
    console.log("Cookie Created."); 
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({

    title: "Create Cookie", 
    contexts:["all"], 
    onclick: createC,

});
```

Obviously the variables used in it are for testing. When I run `document.cookie;` in the console, the cookie does not appear. **I have tried using the `chrome.cookies` API and had the same issue.**

Does the cookie not appear because it is created in the background script? I am trying to set it on the current tab the user is on, not the background page itself.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "MyExtension",
  "description": "Do stuff",
  "version": "0.1",
  "icons": { "16": "icon.png",
           "48": "icon.png",
          "128": "icon.png" },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>", "contextMenus", "cookies"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["script.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["nav.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In background script, 'document' is not for the current page, but for the extension background page(chrome-extension://[your extension id]/bacground.html). So, you can't use 'document.cookie', you need to try [chrome.cookies.get](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-set) like this:

```
/**
 * Create cookie for the special page
 * @param {Object<key, value>} detail
 * @param {Function=} opt_callback
 */
function createCookie(detail, opt_callback) {
  chrome.cookies.set(detail, opt_callback);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this. It returned undefined no matter what.

Comment: You should list your target page url to the manifest.json like this: "permissions": ['your tatget page url']. Maybe, you can do a simple testing, open background page(chrome-extension://[your extension id]/bacground.html), 'F12' to the Console and input chrome.cookies.set({url:'http:\/\/www.google.com\/', name:'test', value:'test'}). Then open [http://www.google.com/](http://www.google.com/) to check the cookie set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript code in specific tab if you want to use the `document` the current page instead of `background.html`.

This can be done by function `executeScript`, your syntax is :

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( tabId, details, callback )
chrome.tabs.executeScript( MyTabIdNumberMandatoryInYourCase, MyScriptCodeInLineOrUrl, MyCallbackOptional )
```

`tabId` matches the `ID` of the **active tab page**, `background.js` file is executed under the main `background.html`, then you need to pass the correct ID if you do not pass it, and hopefully it will execute the `background.html` as the **active tab**.

All `WebRequest` events, has a variable called `details` and she carries a `tabid` value, and you access it via `details.tabId`, below is a code that I use in one of my extensions already created.

```
var onCompletedExecuteScriptDetails = {
  // You can run all the code in the inline form,
  // rather than using the parameter "file", use the "code" parameter, but is very ugly, 
  // is much more elegant to use the "file" mode
  // my-script.js is a file with code to create cookie
  file : "my-script.js"
};

var onCompletedExecuteScript = function ( details ) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript( details.tabId, onCompletedExecuteScriptDetails );
};

var onCompletedCallback = function ( details ) {
  document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', onCompletedExecuteScript( details ) );
};

var onCompletedFilter = {
  urls : [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
  ]
};

chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener( onCompletedCallback, onCompletedFilter, onCompletedInfo );
```

- [executeScript](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.url != null) {
        url = changeInfo.url;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing.

In `manifest.json`:

```
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "*://*.target_website.com/",
    "*://*/_generated_background_page.html"
  ]
```

In `background.js`

```
chrome.cookies.set({
    "name": "cookie's name",
    "url": "the URL you want to apply the cookies to",
    "value": "cookie's value"
}, function(cookie) {
   if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
       console.log(chrome.extension.lastError);
   }

   if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
       console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
   }
});
```